# Passing parameters to C++ CORBA method implementation

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, corba

I'm new to using CORBA and I'm struggling with correctly passing the parameters to a method that I want to invoke. The method has the `IDL` signature

```
void addUpdateListener(out OpStatus opStatus, in IPlanningUpdateListener listener);
```

`OpStatus` is a struct defined as

```
struct OpStatus {
    EComponent EComp;
    EStatus State;
    string Message;
}
enum EComponent { CompA, CompB, CompC };
enum EStatus { SUCCESS, FAILURE, RETRY };
```

and `IPlanningUpdateListener` is itself an `IDL` interface.

I've implemented the `_impl` of the class looks like

```
void addUpdateListener(OpStatus_out opStatus, _objref_IPlanningUpdateListener* listener)    {
    std::cout << "addUpdateListener called\n";
}
```

I've managed to register all my services with the ORB correctly and but I don't know how to actually call this method. I've got a pointer to the service that I want to be added as a listener but it's not of the correct type. Does anyone know why `omniidl` converts the existing OpStatus and IPlanningUpdateListener types in the `IDL` into the new `OpStatus_out` and `_objref_IPlanningUpdateListener` types. I thought for out parameters all I needed to do was pass a reference.

```
IPlanningUpdateListener_impl* listener // initialised and registered earlier
OpStatus opStatus; 
myClass->addUpdateListener(opStatus, listener);
```

My two questions are how do I get this method to accept my implementation of the IPlanningUpdateListener as a parameter and what do I need to do to convert the OpStatus struct into the OpStatus_out type that the `omniidl` has created?

Comment: `_objref_IPlanningUpdateListener*` is an internal type specific to your ORB. Your impl will be more portable if you change the signature to be `IPlanningUpdateListener_ptr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the client change OpStatus to a _var.

```
OpStatus_var opStatus; 
myClass->addUpdateListener(opStatus, listener);
```

The implementation will create a new struct to return.

```
void addUpdateListener(OpStatus_out opStatus, _objref_IPlanningUpdateListener* listener)    
{
  opStats = new OpStatus;

...
}
```

Comment: Explanation: any kind of struct "output" has to pretend to pass memory to the end client.  the _var allows this to happen.  Much like passing in a ref-to-ptr (or ptr-to-ptr), the memory can then be filled in by the framework.

Comment: Changing to `OpStatus_var` was only half the answer. I had to alter the call to `myClass->addUpdateListener(opStatus, listener->_this());` to get it working (or at least compiling!) properly.